# How to find folders with large disk usage? (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, file-management

My harddrive is approaching capacity and I'd like to find all the large folders on the drive to delete them manually.  I searched for a way to do this and a lot of 3rd party utilities came up, but I was surprised I couldn't find a native win7 way of doing it.  I don't have to do this often so I'd prefer not to install a tool specifically for this.  I just need a listing of all folders that exceed a certain size.

Comment: there is no inbox tool. I use this freeware program: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Comment: I found this recently which I really like: http://windirstat.info/

Comment: I don't like this tool. I prefer TreeSizeFree